# Python create a loop if condition not verified

Tags: python

I'm using python 2.6.6 and I can't solve my problem.

I have this code:

```
file = raw_input('Enter the name of the file: ')
try:
    text_file = open(file,'r')
except IOError:
    print 'File not found'
    file = raw_input('Enter the name of the file: ')
    text_file = open(file,'r')
```

How can i turn this into a loop so that if the user inputs a wrong file name or file its not in that location it continues asking for the file?

Regards,

Favolas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while True:
    file = raw_input('Enter the name of the file: ')
    try:
        text_file = open(file,'r')
        break
    except IOError:
        print 'File not found'
```

Comment: Thanks Sven. Before coming here, I've done the exact same code you posted but without the break and it was giving me error. Need to practice more :)